# cmbright and math functions

Tags: math-mode

When using cmbright, the font used for math functions is not the one I would have expected. Is this normal behaviour? What to change to have a consistent font throughout the document ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{beamer}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$\cos$ $\mathsf{cos}$\\
$\log$ $\mathsf{log}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beamer changes the math setup. What you should do depends a bit on which font you want. This here uses the cmbright fonts:

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf} {OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$\cos$ $\mathsf{cos}$\\
$\log$ $\mathsf{log}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. However, it seems that specifying `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` is enough. What is the use of the fourth line in your code?

Comment: I get different fonts if I don't reset \mathsf, by default it uses cmss.